# Cinder JUJU Volume Does not Attach

Tags: juju, openstack

On a multi-node Kilo Openstack, running on 14.04, I am having problem attaching Cinder volumes to an instance. Here are the steps that I took:
1- Created a 100G loopback device,

```
$ sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0801]:35136386 (/var/lib/cinder/volumes/vol1.img)
```

2- Created partition and attached it to cinder-volumes:

```
# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/loop0
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  PV Size               100.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25599
  Free PE               24319
  Allocated PE          1280
  PV UUID               gzJ2HD-oPtg-HrR4-qTnA-OMzQ-Ja1J-n2Zlh
vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               100.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25599
  Alloc PE / Size       1280 / 5.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       24319 / 95.00 GiB
  VG UUID               CKhy2J-zCFG-tJ2W-OD3y-FvbQ-Cf17-vSXY7K
```

3- Created a 5G volume

```
# cinder list
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|                  ID                  |   Status  | Display Name | Size | Volume Type | Bootable | Attached to |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5 | available |      v5      |  5   |     None    |  false   |             |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

4- Tried attaching it to a running instance, through Horizon, and here is what I get from Cinder log file:

```
2015-06-19 22:10:24.847 13448 WARNING cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Persistence file already exists for volume, found file at: /var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:10:58.293 13448 WARNING cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-0d69211a-b4f3-420c-88a5-1cd47c5eedd4 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Persistence file already exists for volume, found file at: /var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:11:39.186 13448 WARNING cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-e1adf523-0024-4890-a8c5-f4d240f8a147 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Persistence file already exists for volume, found file at: /var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:13:07.342 13448 ERROR cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Failed to create iscsi target for Volume ID: volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: None
Exit code: -
Stdout: u"Unexpected error while running command.\nCommand: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgt-admin --update iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\nExit code: 1\nStdout: u''\nStderr: u'Out of memory!\\n'"
Stderr: None
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 ERROR cinder.volume.manager [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Unable to create export for volume 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager     volume)
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager     volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager     chap_auth)
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 233, in create_iscsi_target
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager     raise exception.ISCSITargetCreateFailed(volume_id=vol_id)
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager ISCSITargetCreateFailed: Failed to create iscsi target for volume volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5.
2015-06-19 22:13:07.608 13448 TRACE cinder.volume.manager 
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Exception during message handling: Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Unable to create export for volume 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1089, in initialize_connection
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     raise exception.VolumeBackendAPIException(data=err_msg)
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher VolumeBackendAPIException: Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Unable to create export for volume 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5
2015-06-19 22:13:08.295 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher 
2015-06-19 22:13:08.423 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Returning exception Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Unable to create export for volume 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5 to caller
2015-06-19 22:13:08.423 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-bac379f3-dc20-46b5-88d8-e0dbd1b9585e fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply\n    executor_callback))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch\n    executor_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1089, in initialize_connection\n    raise exception.VolumeBackendAPIException(data=err_msg)\n', 'VolumeBackendAPIException: Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Unable to create export for volume 6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\n']
2015-06-19 22:13:30.416 13448 ERROR cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-d54a6f35-8af9-4464-81f7-c533d7791bb6 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Failed to create iscsi target for Volume ID: volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: None
Exit code: -
Stdout: u"Unexpected error while running command.\nCommand: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgt-admin --update iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\nExit code: 137\nStdout: u''\nStderr: u''"
Stderr: None
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-d54a6f35-8af9-4464-81f7-c533d7791bb6 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Exception during message handling: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     chap_auth)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     os.unlink(volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:13:30.566 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher 
2015-06-19 22:13:30.567 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-d54a6f35-8af9-4464-81f7-c533d7791bb6 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Returning exception [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5' to caller
2015-06-19 22:13:30.568 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-d54a6f35-8af9-4464-81f7-c533d7791bb6 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply\n    executor_callback))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch\n    executor_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection\n    volume)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export\n    volume_path)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export\n    chap_auth)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target\n    os.unlink(volume_path)\n', "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'\n"]
2015-06-19 22:14:00.531 13448 ERROR cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-e1adf523-0024-4890-a8c5-f4d240f8a147 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Failed to create iscsi target for Volume ID: volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: None
Exit code: -
Stdout: u"Unexpected error while running command.\nCommand: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgt-admin --update iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\nExit code: 1\nStdout: u''\nStderr: u'Out of memory!\\n'"
Stderr: None
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-e1adf523-0024-4890-a8c5-f4d240f8a147 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Exception during message handling: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     chap_auth)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     os.unlink(volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:14:00.536 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher 
2015-06-19 22:14:00.552 13448 ERROR cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-0d69211a-b4f3-420c-88a5-1cd47c5eedd4 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Failed to create iscsi target for Volume ID: volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: None
Exit code: -
Stdout: u"Unexpected error while running command.\nCommand: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgt-admin --update iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\nExit code: 1\nStdout: u''\nStderr: u'Out of memory!\\n'"
Stderr: None
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-0d69211a-b4f3-420c-88a5-1cd47c5eedd4 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Exception during message handling: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     chap_auth)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     os.unlink(volume_path)
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'
2015-06-19 22:14:00.555 13448 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher 
2015-06-19 22:14:00.696 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-e1adf523-0024-4890-a8c5-f4d240f8a147 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Returning exception [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5' to caller
2015-06-19 22:14:00.703 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-e1adf523-0024-4890-a8c5-f4d240f8a147 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply\n    executor_callback))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch\n    executor_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection\n    volume)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export\n    volume_path)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export\n    chap_auth)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target\n    os.unlink(volume_path)\n', "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'\n"]
2015-06-19 22:14:00.705 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-0d69211a-b4f3-420c-88a5-1cd47c5eedd4 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] Returning exception [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5' to caller
2015-06-19 22:14:00.705 13448 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-0d69211a-b4f3-420c-88a5-1cd47c5eedd4 fcbce29fa1eb4b42921a20055afdc024 8f3633c4ba1640abbab3be608b6bcc88 - - -] ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply\n    executor_callback))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch\n    executor_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 1084, in initialize_connection\n    volume)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 105, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 606, in create_export\n    volume_path)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 208, in create_export\n    chap_auth)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 232, in create_iscsi_target\n    os.unlink(volume_path)\n', "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/cinder/volumes/volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5'\n"]
```

Few things stand out:
1-  Persistence file already exists for volume..., which sounds like a timing problem
2- looking at the controller machine, where Cinder is installed, tgt-admin, initially consumes a lots of CPU and memeory:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                            
14622 root      20   0 26.158g 0.025t   2036 R  64.7 40.9   0:37.48 tgt-admin                                                                                          
15149 root      20   0 4627140 3.858g   2036 R  61.7  6.2   0:07.32 tgt-admin                                                                                          
  138 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  16.5  0.0   3:05.25 kswapd0
```

, which maybe related to this message: `Stdout: u"Unexpected error while running command.\nCommand: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgt-admin --update iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-6b50b07b-79b6-4733-9049-531b5d68dae5\nExit code: 1\nStdout: u''\nStderr: u'Out of memory!\\n'"`
Here is my cinder.conf file:

```
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# cinder configuration file maintained by Juju
# local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
[DEFAULT]
rootwrap_config = /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf
api_paste_confg = /etc/cinder/api-paste.ini
iscsi_helper = tgtadm
volume_name_template = volume-%s
volume_group = cinder-volumes
verbose = False
debug = False
use_syslog = False
auth_strategy = keystone
state_path = /var/lib/cinder
volumes_dir = /var/lib/cinder/volumes
osapi_volume_workers = 32

notification_driver = cinder.openstack.common.notifier.rpc_notifier
control_exchange = cinder
osapi_volume_listen = 0.0.0.0
osapi_volume_listen_port = 8766
glance_api_servers = http://10.4.0.58:9292
glance_api_version = 1
volume_clear =  none


[keystone_authtoken]
identity_uri = http://10.4.0.61:35357/
auth_uri = http://10.4.0.61:5000/
admin_tenant_name = services
admin_user = cinder_cinderv2
admin_password = YNY8zpzJL77rZHcR3BJZZWV57xPBLcXhnghRNrxCN6S5tXyBq3LZwnZTHHdtpnqf
signing_dir = /var/cache/cinder


[database]
connection = mysql://cinder:RCddjp2FPGnkK5P2sFVbtHzhsPwWFRTZ@10.4.0.53/cinder


[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_userid = cinder
rabbit_virtual_host = openstack
rabbit_password = 7sgRdRjBqHzwZtqLBz22FmkCTSLGrGM7krfwwLm3sJz9NqJ4xfTC6Kx7ShbZBS8y
rabbit_host = 10.4.0.60


[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lock/cinder
```

Running charm version `charm: cs:trusty/cinder-23`
Any thoughts?
Cheers,